# Mobile Website Markup Tags?

Tags: html, ios, mobile, w3c, mobile-phones

Seems like an easy answer to find .. however I have spent hours searching with no luck.

**What are the official tags that developers are supposed to use on mobile web apps?**

Like

```
<callout><phone><map><address>
```

Does w3c have an official list?

Comment: For example, if I wrap a phone number with a tag, like phone, a phone that i smart will add a click to call link around it.

e.g. <phone>123-456-7788</phone>
Then, if the phone is modern, it will automatically create a hyperlink on the phone number to enable a call out feature.

Answer (score 1):

There's such a variety across devices that you'll really have to test on whatever your target devices are. The new smartphones (iPhone, Android-based phones, Palm Pre) all have good web browsers that support all the same tags as the desktop browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [xHTML Mobile Profile](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/affiliates/wap/wap-277-xhtmlmp-20011029-a.pdf) and [WML](http://www.wapforum.org/what/technical/wml-30-apr-98.pdf) for old phones.

Answer (score 0):

On current browsers, it's regular HTML. Old versions of Pocket IE may have issues, but most people who use that are used to issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like the official DocType or mobile browser specific or what?

I don't think web apps that are visited via mobile phone have any kind of official tags to designate this. In fact, [Eric Meyer has written very emotionally](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/08/08/the-veterans-charge/) on the topic of media/browser targeting for iPhones.

The only thing official (and from the w3c) that I know of in regards to web apps and mobile devices is [@media rules for CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html), specifically `@media handheld`.

If  you just want great advice on making web apps for a mobile audience, you should check out:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/putyourcontentinmypocket/